# How to deal with kids playing outside my house?

Tags: home

I live in India. My neighbor's kids play cricket outside my house and keeps scratching and denting my car with the ball. I have talked with the parents and asked them to use a soft or sponge ball rather than a plastic one. But they do not seem cooperative and their tone is not friendly. How do I effectively deal with kids, preferably without involving legal authorities?

Comment: Without being rude, but you live in India while not having an Indian name, and (from their perspective) you want to deprive Indian children from playing the national Indian ballgame, is it possible we are dealing with a culture clash here?

Comment: @dominique While the OP may answer it best, it is possible that Sam is a shortened form of a longer name. As India is a multi-religious country it is also possible that it is his actual name. India's national game is actually Hockey though Cricket is hugely popular & religion for some. As an Indian, I sympathize with Sam and feel the neighbour & their kids are being insensitive.

Answer (score 11):

An increasingly common trick in Britain to deter youngsters from an area is to play them classical music.

This sort of music is seen as highly uncool and they find somewhere else to hang out.

This was discussed at length on the [BBC News Website](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/magazine/4154711.stm) when it first became popular.

The downside in a residential area is that you may annoy the neighbours - or violate noise abatement laws.  It would be worth doing this in concert (sorry!) with your neighbours rather than unilaterally.

Answer (score 4):

As complaining about kids is not "cool", especially when they are small, although it is morally and legally fair. Its good to find an alternative, I'm glad you have started to think about this.

Now, what is a cool way to handle those cute faced tiny lovable monsters?

Step 1: Make friends with them.
You might think this is not worth it on the moment of first thought but trust me playing with kids helps you in many ways

Step 2: Explain your problem to them and they will understand now.

The thing is kids don't like to follow orders, especially if it messes with their favorite things (playing cricket with a hard ball in your case).
But, if friends ask the same, they "listen".

Simple, problem solved and now you have more friends too.

Answer (score 4):

I have an in ground irrigation system tied to my Alexa. For a while when a neighbors dog would use my yard I'd turn on that section of the irrigation system. They stopped.

Answer (score 3):

Proof that the damage to your car is from the kids, bring the parents an official looking document in which you claim payment for the damages.

You can soften that a bit by telling them that you will not take action yet but will do so when there is further damage to the car or any other of your posessions.
When the parents take you serious they will keep the kids from damaging your things.

This is not a friendly way, so it might be better to just talk rather than to bring it to the point.

Answer (score 2):

A simple shelter covering your car is probably the best answer.  A (rigid) car cover, plastic shed or quonset (half-cylinder lying on its side) can be very inexpensive and will keep cricket balls (as well as sun, tree sap, and bird droppings) off your car.  Even a tent would work, as long as it has walls at least on the long sides.

Answer (score 0):

We all have been kids and world was great at those years.Even evil things let us feel cool.Maybe that is why they find your car as a target. But I can suggest a responsible behavior instead of finding a solution to get rid of them.

In your situation if I were you I would take tour with them with your car so your car will became valuable for them too.Be their friends they will even fight for your car :D

Another solution while you have a voice much more than kids speak with municipal authority to make them a place where they can play safely which was rounded by fence.

It would be amazing if you can do it , wouldn't it ?